# Disable blue LED on a LaCie 1TB High-Speed USB 2.0 external drive

Tags: storage

Does anyone know the magic incantation to disable the annoying blue led on the front of a [LaCie 1TB High-Speed USB 2.0 external drive](http://www.lacie.com/au/products/product.htm?pid=11016)?

The manual for that model doesn't mention the ability to disable it, but for the NAS model; there is the option.

Comment: Do answers including screwdrivers count? :)

Comment: If the LED is annoying enough, just remove it!  (Or put opaque tape over it.)

Comment: Am I sensing a common theme here?

Comment: Software configuration preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While a NAS usually (always?) has some method of remote configuration, a USB version of the same drive usually won't.  The NAS requires configuration to know its IP address among other things.  A USB drive does not *require* configuration.

I would be surprised if you have any choice other than some opaque tape or other opaque object to block the LED.  Sorry.

Comment: I shall resign myself to the low-tech approach.

Answer (score 7):

Electrical tape.  Possibly two layers, if your LEDs are anything like the ones on the HDMI switch I just bought.

Comment: Used this technique on many LED lights. Works well, cheap and quick.

Answer (score 3):

Blue tak over the LED :)

In all seriousness, I've never seen a USB enclosure with any configurable options. Reason? Well, a NAS must have a back-end management solution (creating arrays, permissions, etc) which all require expensive (in context) hardware (web server, etc). A USB caddy is a "Dumb" device, it just sits there and translates instructions. It has no back-end configurations.

Your only bet is to use one of the aforementioned solutions...

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the popular solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use white out or a paint marker.

Answer (score 0):

Turn it around.  
stash it out of sight <- (also a theft deterrent).

Answer (score 0):

Black nail polish works wonders on those horrible blue LEDs.

Comment: I can just imagine the looks if someone saw a bottle of black nail polish in my desk drawer... ;)

Comment: Better be careful, as nail polish has acetone, which is an excellent solvent for many plastics, usually those employed in PC cases.

Comment: Nail polish _remover_ contains acetone, typically not the nail polish itself. Nail polish is normally nitrocellulose based with butyl stearate or butanone used as the solvent. They are not very aggressive solvents like acetone is. LEDs themselves are typically encased in clear epoxy which is resistant to the vast majority of solvents.
That said care should be exercised with any paint that is solvent based and test it in an inconspicuous area first.